# select mysql data and set value of a variable based on timestamp column

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select data from a table. This table has a timestamp column.
If the timestamp is more then a year old, then in the result I like to have for that record active=false, otherwise it is active=true.

I can just fetch the result and then loop through it in PHP and set this value like that. But is this also already possible through a certain MySQL select statement?

**The answer from below:**

```
SELECT if(timestamp < now() - interval  1 year,false,true) as active FROM table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like below code,

```
UPDATE 'TABLENAME' SET active='false' WHERE timestamp > '1year'
```

Without updating,

```
SELECT if(timestamp > '1year',false,true) as flag FROM 'TABLENAME'
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to update a table. I could do that. But I wanted it in the SELECT statement only....

Comment: check @user1494552. is this the solution you want??

Comment: check @user1494552. is this the solution you want??

Comment: I am now at SELECT if(now()-edittime > '1day',false,true) as flag FROM table

I think I have to subtract it from now()? Right? Are you sure that '1year' is recognizable as 1 year? Cos it doesn't seem to work yet...

Comment: nope. it is not recognizable. you have to use date functions of mysql for that.

Comment: Ok got it:  SELECT if(edittime < now() - interval  1 year,false,true) as flag FROM table

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that a year has 365 days:

```
update t
    set active = 0
    where timestampcol < unix_timestamp() - (365*24*60*60);
```

Otherwise, you need to do some conversions:

```
update t
    set active = 0
    where timestampcol < unix_timestamp(date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 year))
```

Comment: See my comment at Vivek's response. I wanted to know if it is possible through only the SELECT statement. I don't want to update a table...